# Show asp:Panel stored in different file

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I have an asp page (.aspx) page, and a asp:Panel in it. I use Telerik library but this is irrelevant, I think.

I now need to move the asp:Panel tag outside the main file, into another, stand-alone, .aspx due to file size and work organization.

I moved the aspx content to a new file, and related code in .cs file, separated from the principal one.

On the load_page of the main one I instantiate, through the constructor, the separate panel - the constructor instantiates every control in the panel, especially the , which has the method .Show().

Every member work in the new class, but since I am very new in ASP I do not know how to put the separate aspx code in the former file, since when I call myModalPopup.Show() I have the only effect of a page reload

Extract of panel in separate file:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelId" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="control1" runat="server" />
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="extId" runat="server" TargetControlID="control1">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    //Html/Controls stuff
</asp:Panel>
```

The myPanel.cs

```
protected EditPanel myPanel = new EditPanel();
public class EditPanel: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected Panel myPanel;
    protected HiddenField control1;
    public AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender extender;
    //Other controls

    public EditPanel()
    {
        extender = new AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender();
        control1 = new HiddenField();
        //Other inits
    }
}
```

In main page .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    protected EditPanel editor = new EditPanel();
    //... so on 
}
```

In main page.aspx I tried (without success)

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelId" runat="server">
<!-- #Include virtual="~/path/EditPanel.aspx" -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Please share with us what you coded so far, we can help better

Comment: You don't need another aspx file. Create an ascx control and call it from the form.

Comment: I did as you suggest, all moved in an ascx - yet I cannot obtain the panel to be shown when I do .Show(). I inserted the control in the parent with its class tag <Namespace:MyPanel>. Note: the parent is also an ascx.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve and what the issue is, but perhaps the FindControl method may be useful when you are trying to obtain control references.